# Tough integration problem - complete the square, domain, absolute value, plus/minus.

Tags: integration, trigonometry, absolute-value, integral-domain, completing-the-square

I almost made it through a really tough integration problem, but I ended up with some extraneous +/-'s that I could only eliminate by graphing the solution. Symbolab seems to have the correct answer but IMO they're using illegal operations to get there. Here is my solution:

[image]

Here is my work keeping track of the domains:

[image]

Here is where the pesky +/-'s came in (computing $tan(arcsec(2u))$):

[image]

Here is Symbolab's solution:

[image]

And here are some of the seemingly invalid operations they used to get there:

[image]

I believe that, on the domain in question, $\sqrt[n]{a^n}=|a|$ because $n$ is $2$ and $tan(v)$ is not greater than $0$ on the domain $\{0<v<\frac{\pi}{2}|\frac{\pi}{2}<v<\pi\}$.

Comment: You have not asked a question, I think. You are just complaining that Symbolab is using illegal operations.

Comment: It is not my intent to complain about Symbolab. The questions are "where did I go wrong?", "how does Symbolab get there when they seemingly *cheated*?", and "how do I explain how to solve this problem to my calculus student?"

Comment: I found where I went wrong! While I was careful to consider the domain restrictions during other phases, I failed to do so when figuring $\tan{arcsec(2u)}$.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/95y5U.png

The only thing I'm still wondering about is how to go from $$\ln{(2x-5+2\sqrt{x^2-5x+6})},\{{x>3\}}$$$$\ln{(-2x+5+2\sqrt{x^2-5x+6})},\{{x<2\}}$$
to
$$\ln{|{2x-5+2\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}|}}$$I'm not sure if that simplification is obvious and I should do it, or if it's complex and I should leave the answer as is?

Comment: Whoops that second one should have been$$-\ln{(-2x+5+2\sqrt{x^2-5x+6})},\{{x<2\}}$$Not sure why it won't let me edit.